# PHP conditionals problems

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I've just started a php course and I'm having a hard time with conditionals.

When "make" isnt inputted it should echo "Make is required". And if "year' or "mileage" isnt numeric it should echo "Mileage and Year must be numeric".

The problem is that no matter what happens it is always echoing "Mileage and year must be numeric".

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lucas Rigatto Brino</title>
<?php require_once "bootstrap.php"; ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Tracking Autos for</h1>
<?php
if ( isset($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    echo "<p>Welcome: ";
    echo htmlentities($_REQUEST['email']);
    echo "</p>\n";
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <p>Make:</p>
    <input type="text" name="make" size="60">
    <p>Year:</p>
    <input type="text" name="year">
    <p>Mileage:</p>
    <input type="text" name="mileage">
    <p> </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
</form>
<h1>Automobiles</h1>
<pre>
<?php
if ( !isset($_POST['make']) ) {
    echo "Make is required";
} else if ( (is_numeric(isset($_POST['year']))) || (is_numeric(isset($_POST['mileage']))) === false ) {
    echo "Mileage and year must be numeric";
} else {
    echo ( (isset($_POST['make'])).' '.(isset($_POST['year'])).' / '.(isset($_POST['mileage'])) );
}    
?>
</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is `isset($_POST['make']` in your else statement? It is assumed to be true by your first condition (`!isset($_POST['make']`)

Comment: Your `is_numeric` checks should be `!is_numeric`

Comment: `isset()` return a boolean True/False so your `is_numeric(isset($_POST['year']))` is checking that result and not the value of `$_POST['year']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `is_numeric` checks should be `!is_numeric`. And they should test the value of the variable, not the result of `isset()` (which is just `true` or `false`).

And the last line should print the values of the variables, not the result of `isset()`.

```
    if (!isset($_POST['make']) ) {
        echo "Make is required";
    } else if (!is_numeric($_POST['year']) || !is_numeric(i$_POST['mileage']) ) {
        echo "Mileage and year must be numeric";
    } else {
        echo $_POST['make'] . ' ' $_POST['year'] . ' / ' . $_POST['mileage'];
    }
```